# uninitialized constant routing error even after including the routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a controller file named `univ_profile.rb` which I tried to include in `routes.rb` like so:

```
resources :univ_profiles
```

However I get an error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/univ_profile/index"
```

when I try to access it. I have an `index` method in my controller and also a view file named `index` under `app/views/user_profile/`.

Can anybody suggest where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers in Rails are named like `<a plural word>_controller.rb`. So perhaps `univ_profiles_controller.rb` for your case (although spelling it out as `univeristy_profiles_controller.rb` or thinking of a different name may be better -- up to you). After you do this and update your controller class name and view folder name to match then the routes should start to connect up.

Also, you can use `bundle exec rake routes` to see what routes are defined, what their names are, and what controllers and actions they point to.

Answer (score 2):

- Your controller should be named `univ_profiles_controller.rb`
- The url would be `/univ_profiles` which would yield the index method.
- Your view should be in `app/views/univ_profiles/index.html.erb`